# Perl Print buffering flush

Tags: perl, printing, buffer

I have the following Perl code:

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);

foreach(...)
{
    ...

    foreach(...)
    {
        print("Processing $folder");
        $|=1;
        process($folder);
    }
    ...
}
```

but the print statement works only in the first iteration of the loop and does not print anything after that. Any idea why?

EDIT: I found the reason and have added it in the answer also.
The solution was:

> I added the following line inside the
>   loop and it worked:
>
> select STDOUT;
>
> I think the code in process() function
>   should have been modifying the default
>   output buffer. It was a code written
>   by somebody else!
>
> I am not sure if this is a problem
>   with Perl which allows this or the
>   developer who did not change it back
>   to the default.
>
> The final code looked like this:
>
> ```
> foreach(...)
> {
>     ...
>
>     foreach(...)
>     {
>         select STDOUT;
>
>         print("Processing $folder");
>         $|=1;
>         process($folder);
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> Thanks all...

Comment: Are you sure that there is more than one iteration?

Comment: yeah there is more than one iteration. I tried adding warn statement and it was getting printed multiple times.

Comment: found the issue. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good detective work in tracking down this problem!

I'd like to suggest an alternate solution.

Rather than having `select()` wars with the author of `process()`, you could use the [IO::Handle](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html) interface to STDOUT:

```
use IO::Handle;

foreach(...)
{
    ...

    foreach(...)
    {
        STDOUT->printflush("Processing $folder");

        process($folder);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I added the following line inside the loop and it worked:

```
select STDOUT;
```

I think the code in process() function should have been modifying the default output buffer. It was a code written by somebody else!

I am not sure if this is a problem with Perl which allows this or the developer who did not change it back to the default.

The final code looked like this:

```
foreach(...)
{
    ...

    foreach(...)
    {
        select STDOUT;

        print("Processing $folder");
        $|=1;
        process($folder);
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use sigtrap qw/handler signal_handler normal-signals/;
use feature qw(say);

my $datetime;
$datetime = localtime ();

say "tester started $datetime";

while ( 1 ) {
    select STDOUT;
    $datetime = localtime ();
    say "tester output every second $datetime";
    $|=1;
    sleep ( 1 );
}

sub signal_handler {
    die "\nCaught a signal $!\n";
}
```